# hide an application on windows search

Tags: windows-7, windows

on windows 7 can you hide an application from windows search result?
by windows search I mean the search on start menu.  I don't want to disable windows search or indexing completely.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by not indexing this particular application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop a subtree of files from being indexed by going to `Indexing Options` (literally type that into the start menu) and hit `Modify`. Navigate to and deselect the folder you want not to be indexed.

This should stop it coming up in the start menu.
However, if you want it to not show up in search results at all (i.e. in explorer, actually searching on a drive) you may need to do something more intrusive.

Setting a file or folder as `hidden` will hide it from the search results as long as you have `show hidden files` disabled. You can do this by following [this tutorial](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-hideunhide-a-file-or-folder-in-windows-7/).
To view the files again just re-enable the `show hidden files` (remembering to again disable when you're done accessing them).

Comment: sorry, I just noticed you wanted a runnable program to not show up. This might only work for files (hiding the `.exe`, I'd expect, won't help)